# How to point Android where exactly the Javascript method is?

Tags: javascript, android, webview, android-webview

I'm trying to use a Javascript function within Android, but the thing is that I am getting `method is not defined`. I tried to use another built-in function like `console.log()` and it does work.

So I figured out that my Android app doesn't know where the script is, from which the method should be called. All the scripts are loaded with the HTML before (because I can see in the app what I have produced). This is the sample code (this is not exactly what I want to achieve, just a sample that I need to solve):

```
@JavascriptInterface
    public void showDialog(){
        activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                webView.loadUrl("javascript: method()");
            }
        });
     }
```

Is there any way to point where exactly the method is? Let's say like this:

`file:///android_asset/js/script.js/method` Is there any other option to do so?

Edit, this is how I use the JS Interface:

```
 this.webView.loadDataWithBaseURL(
                "file:///android_asset/",
                this.HTML.html,
                "text/html",
                "UTF-8",
                "");
        this.exportModule= new ExportModule(activity.getBaseContext(), activity, this.webView);
        this.webView.addJavascriptInterface(exportModule, "jsint");
```

Comment: if the JS sources are usid in your HTML page, then you don't have to point the pass. I think you are trying to use the method **before** your page finishes loading, therefore the JS you want to use is not finished loading when you try it.

Comment: Well, I thought the same but the thing is that everything is loaded because I see all the result exactly as it should be. Additionally I put the code how I add the JS Interface

Comment: The thing is that I can run this method if I do it directly from JavaScript code

Comment: I really don't understand what you are doing. If you want Javascript code. Just add a JS file to a html file and load that HTML page.

Comment: @Steven I will tell you then. I've got the JS file loaded to my HTML, I have my HTML loaded to `WebView`. The thing I want is to determine by Android app which method from JS should be called. This is what I want to do.

Comment: Okey I understand what you want. I find it a bit strange what you want because I don't see the use of what you want to do with that. I don't know if it is possible in android native maybe with cordova? If you want to log something in your JS and use that In your android that is possible.